# What should I wear to academic ceremonies in UK? I have a PhD from Austria

Tags: academic-dress

What should I personally wear to academic ceremonies in UK? I have a PhD from VetMedUni, Vienna (Austria) and they do not have academic regalia. But in the UK we are expected to wear our academic robes to formal events, such as when our students graduate. I have read that other's with foreign PhDs sometimes wear the regalia of their home country, which I really like the idea of. In Austria it is not uncommon to wear a dirndl for graduation. I didn't have a graduation ceremony (lockdowns and moving home), but if I had, I dreamed of a dirndl. I think it would be nice to honour Austria in this way and adopt a Dirndl as my academic dress, but I am not Austrian. Would this be considered to be inappropriate or cultural appropriation since I'm British? Alternatively/as well should I just wear my Master's gown? Thank you

Comment: Can you ask the professors, dean, or coworkers at your workplace or academic institute ? They may give you some great suggestions. -- BTW, as you propose, many people would think that "**it would be nice to honour Austria in this way and adopt a Dirndl as my academic dress**".

Comment: As an Austrian myself (though out of the country for a long time by now), I would absolutely say a dirndl would be appropriate. [It's a very young tradition, anyway](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirndl), and being "appropriated" left, right and center. Absolutely great to wear it at a festive occasion like graduation!

Answer (score 1):

For graduation specifically, most universities engage the services of a rober such as Ryder & Amies or Ede & Ravenscroft to source robes and Hoods for staff who attend the ceremonies,  and the staff of these companies will know what the appropriate dress is.

I've not heard of people wearing national dress instead of gown/hood, but instead of a suit underneath.  I could be wrong though.

As whether you can wear them even thought you are not Austrian, but just studied there,  I think this would be a little odd,  but I don't think anyone would stop you, in fact people would probably think it fun.